# Multiple Join Optimization in ActiveRecords Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

There are four models: Car, Person, Country and Religion.

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  has_one :country, through: :person
  has_one :religion, through: :person

  def self.get_indian_cars_owned_by_hindus
    self.joins(:country).joins(:religion).where("countries.name=? and religions.name=?", 'India', 'Hindu').count
  end
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :religion
  has_one :car
end

class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :persons
end

class Religion < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :persons
end
```

The function get_indian_cars_owned_by_hindus inside model Cars applies some condition on tables countries & religions. The query that gets generated when the function is called is this:

`` SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `cars` INNER JOIN `persons` ON `persons`.`id` = `cars`.`person_id` INNER JOIN `countries` ON `countries`.`id` = `persons`.`country_id` INNER JOIN `persons` `persons_cars_join` ON `persons_cars_join`.`id` = `cars`.`person_id` INNER JOIN `religions` ON `religions`.`id` = `persons_cars_join`.`religion_id` WHERE (`countries`.`name` = 'India') AND (`religions`.`name` = 'Hindu'); ``

I initially expected the query to be this:

`` SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `cars` INNER JOIN `persons` ON `persons`.`id` = `cars`.`person_id` INNER JOIN `countries` ON `countries`.`id` = `persons`.`country_id` INNER JOIN `religions` ON `religions`.`id` = `persons`.`religion_id` WHERE (`countries`.`name` = 'India') AND (`religions`.`name` = 'Hindu'); ``

ActiveRecords here is not optimizing an extra join between persons and cars tables. While I believe mysql will optimize this at it's end, what's the way to write this correctly in `the rails way`.

I obviously can move the method inside model persons, but that's not the solution I am looking for. There can be cases where there are more than one nodes.

EDIT: Chaging model names from A, B, C and D to Car, Person, Country and Religion

Comment: A real world example would be easier to understand, for folks like me who don't have abstract skill high enough.

Comment: This would be easier to follow if there was something concrete like the usual blog example with users/posts/etc instead of abcd.

Comment: How does the real life example matter ?

Comment: It's easier to understand.

Comment: Hope my last edit helps!

Comment: The design looks cleaner and easier to understand..

Comment: What does your migration look like that created these tables? A 1-to-1 relationship like Car and Person have here does not need a join table, and ActiveRecord shouldn't have created one.

Comment: there tables have not been generated using migration... i have manually created the models and put in the associations.. something wrong fundamentally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best bet would be changing the `join` call to not use the `has_many :through` relationships. Instead you can nest the deep relationships in an array, like this:

```
def self.get_indian_cars_owned_by_hindus
  self.joins(:person => [:country, :religion]).
  where("countries.name=? and religions.name=?", 'India', 'Hindu').
  count
end
```

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for... though, i still don't understand why activerecords doesn't do this internally.

Comment: It reflects on the models' associations to find table names and foreign keys. It does not recognise that both `country` and `religion` are bound to `Car` by the same table (`people`). So it generates two `INNER JOIN` statements, each one with its own version if the table `people`.

Comment: This does not happen when you use the hash syntax because you are explicitly telling AR: Join `person` relation. Also, using the same table, join `country` and `religion`.